# Capybara- how to select multiple table rows using xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I want to select multiple table rows the same time. table row 2 and table row 3 they both have the same id, is there a way to select the two table rows at the same time? currently I am trying to approach using xpath in-order to do that I need to join the two xpath but no luck so far.

here is my sample:

```
    find(:xpath, ".//*[@id='review']/tr[2]/td[2]")
    find(:xpath, ".//*[@id='review']/tr[3]/td[2]")
```

so I just want to select the two table rows (tr[2]and tr[3]) then they both highlighted(selected)

Comment: Can you give the html also?

Comment: The 2 rows have the same id? Then by `.//[@id='review']/tr[2]/td[2]`, you probably meant `.//tr[2][@id='review']/td[2]`, and selecting rows 2 and 3, that have the same id, would be `.//tr[position()=2 or position()=3][@id='review']/td[2]`. But as Arup said, posting the HTML would help.

Comment: thanks for your response Arup and Paul , I try to run find(:xpath, ".//[@id='review']/tr[position()=2 or position()= 3]/td[2]") but my script throws "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified." here is an html example , I am using the top level id, so I can able to search tr[2] and tr[3] individually using id "review" so my aim is to select both ids together    <html>
<body>
<tbody id="review">
   <tr id ="randomenum1"> 
   <tr id ="randomenum2">
   <tr id ="randomenum3">
/tbody>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ah so `tbody` has an id. Try `.//*[@id='review']/tr[position()=2 or position()=3]/td[2]`

Comment: tbody has id, I run the script but it return an error Ambiguous match, hmm each table have td[2], that what I want to select